# Facebook - ways to notify non app users

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-fql

Is there any other way expect "requests 2.0"
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ to send short message to non app users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other option is to let uses send messages with the [Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/). However, this does not provide any feedback to you the way app requests do: the best you can typically do is put in a link and check to see if it gets clicked by the recipient. But otherwise no, currently apprequests are the only way to send messages.

Comment: yeah "post to wall" app last few hours before automated system disable this feature .

Answer (score 1):

The only other way is to write on friends walls - but that is a way to get your app marked as spam if you aren't very careful with it.  The requests dialog doesn't have an API, Facebook won't give you a friends email address, and it won't let you send Facebook messages to friends any more via the api.